# Get List.Count of items in child property of collection bound to DataGridView

Tags: c#, xaml, datagridview, devexpress, maui

I have a DevExpress `DataGridView` in my XAML page whose content is bound to a collection of `Document` objects. Each of those objects contains a list of Items. I want to display the number of items on the DataGridView next to each `Document` element. I added a TextColumn for it and `Items.Count` as the `FieldName` but it stays blank.

```
<dxg:DataGridView.Columns>
    <dxg:TextColumn Row="0" Column="0" FieldName="DocumentNumber" ColumnSpan="2" Caption="Code" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="20" />
    <dxg:TextColumn Row="0" Column="2" FieldName="Items.Count" HorizontalContentAlignment="End" FontAttributes="Bold">
        <dxg:TextColumn.UnboundExpression>
            <Binding Path="Items.Count"/>
        </dxg:TextColumn.UnboundExpression>
    </dxg:TextColumn>
</dxg:DataGridView.Columns>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have defined an `Items` Collection in `Document` object,  you may try using `TemplateColumn`

```
    <dxg:TemplateColumn FieldName="Items" Caption="Count" MinWidth="200">
        <dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="15, 0, 0, 0">
                
                    <Label Text="{Binding Value.Count}" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold"
                    TextColor="Yellow"  Grid.Row="0" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
    </dxg:TemplateColumn>
```

---

[Unbound Column](https://docs.devexpress.com/MAUI/DevExpress.Maui.DataGrid.DataGridView#unbound-columns) is used to display data values calculated based on values of other columns.

Here are some [Examples of UnboundExpression](https://docs.devexpress.com/MAUI/DevExpress.Maui.DataGrid.GridColumn.UnboundExpression#examples). It's hard to use here.

Hope it helps!